# How often is total score for a tag calculated

Tags: discussion, tags

How often is my total score for a particular tag calculated. I've gotten several recent upvotes under android but my total score hasn't seem to have gone up. When I say total score, I mean like the total score displayed on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers).

Comment: Total score as shown in which page/section?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: About once a day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As agf said, once a day. I’ve been monitoring it today and it’s just been updated, so it seems that it’s updated around 3:00 UTC (maybe one hour off due to DST).

Comment: UTC has no notion of DST. That's why it's an UTC :)

Comment: @Chi Sure, but the servers may be configured to run the update at, say, 20:00 regardless of it being PDT or PST.

Comment: All Stackexchange servers run in UTC timezone.

Comment: @Chi No one hour off, then. :)