# Tag score not updated

Tags: support, tag-score

I've long had a score of 99 in the `C++` tag on Stack Overflow. 4 hours ago, I got an upvote on a C++ answer, but I still have a score of 99 and haven't gotten the badge. It isn't a Community Wiki question, and there are no downvotes in my history that could have canceled it out.

What's going on? The weirdest part is that I did get reputation for the update, but no badge.

Comment: Patience, grasshopper, it will come.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my experience, the tag score update takes some time due to caching. Wait for a couple of days more and check. It should be updated by then. As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109890/200687), it is updated around 3:00 UTC.

Comment: I've been waiting for a couple of days but no signs of an update. I suppose I'll wait another day and file a bug report if it still doesn't