# Tag scores not updating on website, updated in App

Tags: bug, tags

My tag scores according to my profile have not been updated on the site for the last few days.  I thought that it was due to something similar to this question:

[Tag score not updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169954/tag-score-not-updated)

However, when checking out my profile in the Android App, the scores are being updated.