# Is there a problem with tag score calculation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-score

According to the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109788/how-often-is-total-score-for-a-tag-calculated), tag score should be calculated once a day around 3:00 UTC. However, I noticed that my score wasn't updated last night for some tags for which I got upvotes yesterday. And prior to that I noticed that an upvote I got was added to the tag scores only after 2-3 days. Is there a problem with the calculation process? Was its frequency changed?