# When does the tag info update on profile?

Tags: discussion, tags

When does the tag info (i.e. numbers including `255,93,131...` in the following image) change? Will it be updated daily? It seems it is not updated at the same time of the start of a new SO day, which is `UTC time 00:00`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are updated daily at **03:00 UTC**, not 00:00 UTC.

Comment: For all these numbers related to tags?

Comment: Yes, they all get updated when the process runs.

Comment: Where can I find these times for changes? Like documentation.

Comment: @herohuyongtao http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109788/how-often-is-total-score-for-a-tag-calculated

Comment: @JoshC No, I am looking for the times for updating, not tag badges.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Pretty much everything that is cached-daily will update at 03:00 UTC. It's documented very well throughout *many* questions scattered across Meta.

Comment: @animuson I think something is wrong here. It's now UTC 05:00+, but my tag number, say 93 (c++) is not updated against yesterday. I am pretty sure about this and I did earn some more points throughout the day.

Comment: @herohuyongtao If you can prove it's not updating, you're better off filing a bug report. It wouldn't be the first time the process has crashed and stopped updating the tag scores.

Comment: @animuson Where should I report to?

Comment: @herohuyongtao Here on Meta, use the [meta-tag:bug] tag. But make sure you provide details to quickly prove it's not actually working. Will prevent a lot of "how do you know?" comments from appearing.

Comment: @animuson I just did, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217040/tag-info-not-update-regularly-on-profile.