# Tag info not updated regularly on profile?

Tags: support, tags

From my [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217038/when-does-the-tag-info-update-on-profile), I learned that all tag related info on profile will be updated daily at `UTC 03:00`.

However, something is wrong here. It's now `UTC 05:00+`, but my tag number, say 93 (c++) is not updated against yesterday. I am pretty sure about this and I did earn some more points throughout the day. Sorry for not be able to capture the screenshot yesterday, but I did check this number 10 hours ago (which belongs to yesterday, also 93).

Is there a bug happening here? Or updating time different?

[image]

**UPDATE**: As of 24 Jan, the tags are still not updated with the proper values.

**UPDATE2**: Fixed around `25 Jan, UTC 03:00`, at least for me.

Comment: The tags do not update from time to time but it should sort itself out the next day.

Comment: @Szymon Yes, probably. But still want to figure out when. Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking that too. Because it also affects a tags top users. It would be good if it displayed how fresh that information is. "Last updated X hours ago".

Comment: FYI, UTC 10AM on 24th and still not updated.

Comment: More upvotes means the problem has not been fixed yet. :(

Comment: Seems to be fixed, at least for me.

Comment: @joeytje50 Yeah, also fixed for me. Updated the question.

Comment: @herohuyongtao - Uh oh! It looks like it's less-than-working as of mid-February.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are some database timeouts happening in the scheduled jobs that recalculate those scores starting on Jan 22 2014. This job is one of the most expensive things that are done on the site, we're trying to optimize it even further. I'll let you know when the fix will be pushed out.

Comment: The tags don't seem to be up updated today (23 Jan) either.

Comment: Nope me neither. I am missing at least 4 votes in the xsd tag from the past few days

Comment: scheduled task failed again (23 Jan), investigating

Comment: @m0sa is there any way to see the service status ourself or does it always have to be a mod look into it?

Comment: only a developer can look into issues such as this.

Comment: @m0sa Still not working on 24 Jan.

Comment: @Satpal I think most of us just care that they are actively investigated it.

Comment: @m0sa - Hello! This appears to still be an issue as of mid-February.

Comment: @m0sa: *I'll let you know when the fix will be pushed out* Until a fix has been found, can you remove the `status-completed` tag from this post? See [Tag scores on user profile are not updated again - worth bringing up on meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221960) for a current meta question on wether you want to be poked every time the script fails.

Comment: @m0sa It appears that this is still an issue it was reported again today [Tag totals not updating](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222633/tag-totals-not-updating)

Comment: @bluefeet Haven't been updated the last 2 days to be precise.

Comment: @m0sa poke. Any updates?

Comment: For me, the tags summary has not been updated for 3 days (01 local time, 06.03.2014)

Comment: The same problem has been happening for the last 2 or 3 days.

Comment: @m0sa This is broken again. Tag counts haven't been updated for the last 2 days on SO, I think. It's it going to be fixed for good?

Comment: @Szymon If you want to draw attention to an issue, please make a new post. A bounty on an old resolved post is hard for us to track and notice.

Comment: @AnnaLear Ok, will do that. I had my posts closed as duplicate in such a situation previously though so I didn't create a new post this time.

Comment: @AnnaLear I've created a new question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226681/tag-counts-are-not-updated-and-the-issue-is-getting-worse

Comment: The error has reappeared - my tagcount has not been updated in three days ...