# Tag rankings not updating regularly

Tags: bug, tags, rankings

It is my understanding that the tag rankings are supposed to be updated every 24 hours. It has been at least 72 hours and the number of votes / answers written in [opengl](/questions/tagged/opengl) in my profile and on the "Top Users" page has not been updated.

My reputation has gone up > 300 pts in the past 72 hours but those counts have remained the same, and I know that they are all OpenGL related because those are the only questions I answer.

Is this a bug or have the ranking calculation intervals changed? I realize updating rankings is not a cheap operation, but it used to occur relatively regularly (or at least more frequently than 72 hours).

Comment: They've been having a *lot* of problems with this script lately.

Comment: [The question Animuson is referring to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217040/tag-info-not-update-regularly-on-profile).

Comment: Yes, it's not working from time to time which is mildly annoying. But the most important thing is, it eventually runs and updates correctly.