# Tag scores on user profile are not updated again - worth bringing up on meta?

Tags: bug, meta, tag-score

Tag scores on user profile are not updated again. That also happened a few days ago (and lasted 3 or 4 days).

General question though: is it worth bringing it up on meta when it happens? This problem happens from time to time but then resolves itself. It's a minor annoyance really, nothing more, in my opinion.

Comment: It is clear the Stack Overflow data set is getting too large for the script. From [Tag info not update regularly on profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217040) we learned that the devs are aware of it and trying to optimize the query further, but I guess that they are not quite in a position yet to declare victory. Unfortunately, they also marked that post as `status-completed` when clearly it is not.