# Tag totals not updating

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/170292/score-per-tag?UserId=256196), I have 1003 total score in the regex tag, but [my user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian?tab=tags) says I only have 999 (I only noticed this because I expected to see a gold badge to appear sooner or later).

Given that the data the query is using is from a migration that happened many hours ago, shouldn't my user profile be updated by now?

Has an update process failed to run?

Comment: Might be deleted questions, check your "deleted recent answers" to verify.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no. nothing there. it's not that.

Comment: @bluefeet It does seem like a dup, but I'll leave this Q to raise a red flag and delete tomorrow if fixed.