# Tag scores are not updated and the issue is getting worse

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-badges, tag-score

Tag scores update is supposed to happen at 03:00 UTC every day. Tag scores are updated by a scheduled job that is time consuming and often times out  (see for example the answers for [Tag info not updated regularly on profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217040/tag-info-not-updated-regularly-on-profile/) and [Tag scores have not updated; script did not run](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178114/tag-scores-have-not-updated-script-did-not-run)).

In the past month or two, the issue with not updating the scores has gotten much worse. Tag scores are now regularly not updated for 2-3 days in a row. The job fails more often than it runs which obviously lowers usability and appeal of tag badges (which are not awarded when the script fails) and scores to some extent.

I can also guess that if a job fails on consecutive days, it only makes it harder to make it work as it has more and more tags and answers to recount.

This issue happened in the past but not to the extent it's happening now.

Please do not close it as duplicate. I'm creating a separate post as I've been asked to do it by Adam Lear in a comment for the answer for the first of the linked questions. Other posts reporting this issue have accepted answers which makes them difficult to track for the SE team.

**UPDATE**

I've been writing down whether the scores were updated or not every day in April.

The results are:

```
Day      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  
Updated  -   -   -   ✓   -   ✓  -   -   -   -   -   ✓   -   -   - 

Day      16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
Updated  ✓   -   ✓   -   ✓   -   -   ✓  ✓   -   ✓  -   ✓   -   -
```

The update succeeded on 10 days, failed on 20. The situation got somewhat better in the second half of the month. Has something been done about it?

Comment: Question is, how important are the tag scores? Won't it be better to ditch the whole thing, now that the user profile is going under a major change anyway?

Comment: @ShadowWizard For me, it is important - it's like detailed reputation for specific areas of knowledge. Also, see how Careers website features your score in tags.

Comment: I'll keep track of how the tag count update goes in April and update the question with the results at the end of the month. So far it failed on the first 3 days.

Comment: My tags score has not been updated for more than 4 days: http://stackoverflow.com/users/114029/leniel-macaferi?tab=tags

Comment: It has been like that for a couple of days now again on Stack Overflow. Reading that this issue comes up every 2-3 months at least, why is it not fixed for "once and all"? OK, bugs can always happen, but it is a bit too frequent IMHO.

Comment: Yes, so far in April it worked on 2 days only: 4th and 6th of April.

Comment: Same problem for top-users pages.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Also top-users pages are not updated for maybe a week or so.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm pretty sure I've earned the gold [tag:matlab] badge, but my tag scores aren't recomputing to give me the badge. It's very irritating. Are the tag badges not relying on the tag scores to be updated?

Comment: @chappjc Tag badges are based on tag scores so they are not given when the tag score update script fails.

Comment: @Szymon That's my point. My comment was a rhetorical question. Shadow Wizard questioned the importance of tag scores altogether and my response is, "I want my gold badge, pretty please update the tag scores."

Comment: @chappjc and Szymon guess you're right, didn't think of the badges. Guess the problem has bigger impact than I thought then.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just got my badge. :D  I guess someone ran the script manually... we'll see if it goes every day now.

Comment: @chappjc the problem isn't with the script being automatic, it's failing due to heavy load on the database. So even when run manually it has same chances of failure/success. Glad it worked this time! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard My thinking was that the timeout was in a cron script or whatever they use. I didn't realize it was a database query itself timing out.  Whatever the reason, I'd venture that someone did something in response to the attention drawn by your generous bounty... so, thanks!

Comment: Wait... maybe it's forming a secret morse code that send us some message? :D

Comment: I think it havent been updated for more than a week now. Last time it was previous saturday if I rmember correct

Comment: This issue hasn't unfortunately been solved yet. Still experiencing the same delay (4gg) as of today

Comment: This issue still hasnt been solved yet. I do not experience any delay. Its just not updated at all.

Comment: Days have gone by with no update, again. Hello? Is there anybody there?

Comment: The problem is going rampart these days. Stack Overflow hasn't been updated for at least three days.

Comment: Seems like the tags in Stack Overflow (Top users in question tag, Tags in the Profile) had not been updated since the week of 11 December 2023.

Answer (score 27):

The tag script now has not run for at least three days now. I know that this question is from March 2014, but this issue is absolutely not fixed.

I could make a list of the tens of duplicates about this issue, but that would be somewhat of a waste of time. It harms those of us like me ([lookup site](http://output.jsbin.com/azeqec/12)) on the edge of getting our gold tag badges from doing our best to help the site, and it's also discouraging when we work hard specifically get a badge and it just never appears.

Please fix this issue!

Comment: I guess that real fix for this is either too complex (e.g. would take several weeks of full time dev work), or would require too much resources (e.g. 100TB of storage or something crazy like that), hence no response from the team.

Comment: This currently also not working for me. Are there any updates?

Comment: Still not working for me on stackoverflow section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like now, the tag scores are getting updated in real-time.