# What are these counts actually?

Tags: support, tag-score

What is 60 and 90 in following?

[image]

As far as I know 60 is the score and 90 is number of posts in [java](/questions/tagged/java).

If it is so, I have observed that since last 4 to 5 days, I have received some upvotes for questions I have answered in [java](/questions/tagged/java) but I am not able to see any change in the count. Why is it so?

Comment: Caching. Always caching.

Comment: The job that updates those counts runs once a day and sometimes fails. Those aren't meant to instantly reflect your upvotes.

Comment: The 90 is not only the number of answers in [tag:java]. It's the count of answers *and questions* in [tag:java].

Comment: "*sometimes*" - read ["nearly always"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226681/223030).

Comment: Nope guyz, I have tried cleaning everything but still it shows the same! :(

Comment: Stack Exchange has the most confusing UI ever.

Comment: This is a server side cache. There's nothing you can do to change that.

Comment: may i expect it to change some day or just forget it!?

Comment: @VD' we can't know for sure if it will be ever be stable. Maybe tomorrow, maybe next week or next year and maybe never. This is not a critical thing, the whole tag score is just something "nice to have". If the team will see it's taking too much of their time to maintain, I assume they will just remove the whole thing.